# Update Header table using details table max value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `tblNews` table & `tblNewsDetails` table. If `max_cap` field is 0 then I need to check the Details tables `cap_dtl` fields last value and update the `max_cap` field.

Table `tblNews` has more than 1 lakth of record with max_cap 0, then can't do this one by one using a query.

```
Select * 
from [dbo].[tblNewsDetails] as a 
where a.news_header_id IN 
                         (
                            Select news_header_id 
                            from [dbo].[tblNews]
                            where max_cap = 0
                         )
group by a.news_header_id
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and_ expected result as properly formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: You can find [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302472/12492890) helpful to improve your tables format.

Comment: @jarlh OP updated in current attempt

Comment: Lakth is not a universsl unit of measure, please use terms everyone can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE and the `row_number` window function e.g.

```
with _list  as(
    select 
        Cap_dtl
        , a.news_header_id
        , row_number() over (partition by a.news_header_id order by Cap_dtl desc) as rw
    from [dbo].[tblNews] a
    inner join tblNewsDetails b
        on a.news_header_id = b.New_Header_id
    where max_cap=0
)
update a
    set max_cap=Cap_dtl
from tblNews  a
inner join _list t
    on a.news_header_id = t.news_header_id
where rw = 1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Hfkpuz8)